Unity Index Out of Range Issue
After running this code :
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Blocks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject blockPrefab;

    [Space]
    public int totalBlocks;

    public float xGap;

    public float yGap;

    public int blocksPerRow;

    public Color[] colors;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Reset()
    {
        List<GameObject> blocksToDestroy = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            blocksToDestroy.Add(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);

        foreach (GameObject block in blocksToDestroy)
            DestroyImmediate(block);

        blocksToDestroy.Clear();
    }

    [ContextMenu("Place")]

    void Place()
    {
        Reset();

        int currentBlocksInRow = 0;
        int currentRow = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalBlocks; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = transform.position;
            position.x += xGap * currentBlocksInRow;
            position.y += yGap * currentRow;

            GameObject newBlock = Instantiate(blockPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
            newBlock.transform.parent = transform;
            newBlock.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[currentRow];


            currentBlocksInRow++;
            if (currentBlocksInRow >= blocksPerRow)
            {
                currentRow++;
                currentBlocksInRow = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


error arise :

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Blocks.Place () (at Assets/Scripts/Blocks.cs:49)

I am trying to resolved this issue & I expected that I will get solution from stackoverflow plateform.

It looks like you're trying to get the currentRow-th element from colors, are you certain you have enough elements in there?

I suppose line 49 is this one: newBlock.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[currentRow];  (would have been cool if you mentioned that in your question). However there's no code shown where you add any elements to the colors-array, so what do you expect?

Use your debugger to see where exactly the exception is thrown and which elements exist (if any at all) in your array.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain a quirk of Unity is that the array can have been populated inside the editor. It doesn't necessarily need to happen in the code itself.

Does this answer your question? What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?

@Ruzihm the link you provided is not answer my question

@MakePeaceGreatAgain how to use debugger to see exceptions ?

Looks like you're trying to access an element of colors that does not exist. Look at the value of totalBlocks, you need to have at least that many elements in colors before running Place().

How to resolved ?

Add the necessary amount of elements to colors in the inspector.

done I code it again
